# Is there any fixed expression meaning spending a lot of time and visiting a lot of shops?

Tags: british-english, phrase-requests

I do not mean "retail therapy" or "a shopping frenzy". I am looking for a verbal expression. I guess this would be close to "hit the town" or "hit the shops" but I am unsure about using these two. Is there any obvious and natural alternative?

Comment: "Shop 'til you drop"? "Desultory shopping trip"? "Conspicuous consumption"? "Shopping spree"? "Retail theft"? (Just kidding!) Don

Comment: "Shopping spree" is probably the most common phrase in the US.

Comment: I agree with @rhetorician. *They shopped till they dropped.*

Comment: What do you mean by "a verbal expression"? Isn't "retail therapy" a verbal expression?

Answer (score 1):

A person who would show such behaviour could be called a shopaholic. "Shopaholic" is also an adjective. Thus you can use it to devise personal locutions that will involve specifically the concept you refer to. I don't know for this concept of any verbal locution or single word verbal form that would be defined in a dictionary.

*Examples*

- she goes on shopaholic bouts, going on shopaholic bouts
- she indulges daily in shopaholic buying , indulging daily in shopaholic buying

Comment: She seems to be looking for a verb.

Comment: @Barmar It is not too hard then, using this term, to make up various expressions that will be verbal locutions: "She goes on shopaholic bouts", "she indulges daily in shopaholic buying "… I don't know a verbal phrase or a verb that would be defined by a dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

A phrasal verb with a similar meaning is «gad around.» ***The Cambridge dictionary*** states ([link](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gad-about-around-somewhere?q=gad%20around)):

> to visit or travel to a lot of different places, enjoying yourself and not worrying about other things you should be doing.

In this situation you can say:

> I spent the day gadding around visiting some shops.

Comment: "most suitable", "best", etc. are opinions, not facts. It's a fact that it's a possibility. It's an opinion that it's the "most suitable" possibility.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I would take into account your remark to crudely represent the dictionary explanations.

Comment: I would be obliged if you gave feedback on my edit

Comment: "The" means there's only one. I imagine that there are many such phrases. "A phrasal verb" would be more factual.

Comment: Now, is it grammatically correct?

Comment: It's much better now. You probably got the downvote because "to gad around" is not connected to shopping, as your answer illustrates by having to mention shopping in addition to gadding around.

Comment: So, should I delete this answer? I don't know yet the rules of this, more advanced than ell.stackexchange, community. My answer is appropriate (?), and what's wrong with the repetition in the sentence?

Comment: Note that the definition of "gadding about" has nothing to do with shopping. You can do both at the same time but it's like listening to the radio while driving. One doesn't mean the other. It's up to you if you want to delete it or not. If you feel you can defend "gadding about" as a correct answer, by all means leave it here. A fixed expression is usually an idiom with a fixed form. (I'm not telling you what to do, just giving you advice.)

Comment: And I'm grateful for it! Sorry, my ruthless nurture is not willing to delete it. Indeed, I'm neither angry nor disappointed, I'm elated to see proficient English users surrounding and criticising me - good for my command of English.